# C# Elastic search - Nest query / filtering

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm pretty new to elastic search / NEST and need some help how to be able to query/filter my data.

I have a list of products. And those products can have any number of options with values connected to them. And I need to be able to filter products by the name of the option and it's values.

I've tried to put together a image with the question :)

[image]

I don't have the reputation yet to embed images :(

The incoming search/filter parameters is dynamic so there can be any number of options with values.

Hope someone can help me in the right direction!

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just include this information as text?

Comment: I needed to be able to mark some parts with a pen :)

Comment: So, you need to search for documents that can contain at least one `Size` value **and** at least `Color` value?

Comment: It should be possible to search for documents that has any option(s) / value(s) defined.

Comment: So if I have a product that has only one option defined. Let's say "Size" in this case, but tha product exist in two sizes so it has two values, let's say "16" and "17". So if I would do a product filter for size and define that I want to see products in Size "16" i should get a match and if I defined "16" AND "19" I would get a match.

Comment: I could also define that I only want to see products with Size 16,19 and with Color = Red and Blue. The different options / values isn't hardcoded/defined so the user can define them for each product in a admin backend.

Answer (score 1):

```
  var results = client
                            .Search<YourMappingEntity>(s => s
                            .Type("page")                            
                            .Filter(f => f
                            .Bool(bb => bb
                            .Must(ms =>
                            {
                                FilterContainer filterContainer = null;
                                filterContainer &=
                                   ms.Term("Size", yourarrayofsizes) &&
                                   ms.Terms("Color", yourarrayofcolors) ;


                                return filterContainer;
                            })))
```

Comment: Does this help in some way?

Comment: Well, looks ok, but it marks FILTER  / BOOL / FilterContainer and Term with red. Perhaps the syntax is for an older version of NEST?

Comment: Could be..i'm using v1.0.0.0

Comment: Hmm..maybe you can check their site https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/index.html

Comment: I did that, but I need it as a NEST example. Still a rookie in this area :/

Answer (score 0):

So after some research and hacking, this is what I came up with and it's working as expected :)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bepVX.png